# How to match job id to a rule shell script

Tags: snakemake

I just finished my bowtie2 alignment jobs by snakemake.
But as you know, bowtie2 output a align summary:

```
23774776 reads; of these:
  23774776 (100.00%) were paired; of these:
    5928889 (24.94%) aligned concordantly 0 times
    17845887 (75.06%) aligned concordantly exactly 1 time
    0 (0.00%) aligned concordantly >1 times
    ----
    5928889 pairs aligned concordantly 0 times; of these:
      1214536 (20.49%) aligned discordantly 1 time
    ----
    4714353 pairs aligned 0 times concordantly or discordantly; of these:
      9428706 mates make up the pairs; of these:
        6563535 (69.61%) aligned 0 times
        2843810 (30.16%) aligned exactly 1 time
        21361 (0.23%) aligned >1 times
86.20% overall alignment rate
```

This summary was wroten in the following files:

```
snakejob.align.601.sh.e6589895
snakejob.align.602.sh.e6591632
snakejob.align.603.sh.e6591988
snakejob.align.604.sh.e6591623
snakejob.align.605.sh.e6591927
snakejob.align.606.sh.e6591628
snakejob.align.607.sh.e6590473
snakejob.align.608.sh.e6591280
snakejob.align.609.sh.e6590190
snakejob.align.610.sh.e6590903
```

There was no sample name in the summary. I think the snakejob id (6**) may hava a relationship with the sample name.

I have checked the files in the hidden folder .snakemake/metadata, the message in the file looks like:

```
{"rule": "PE", "shellcmd": "/soft/samtools/samtools view -bF 12 /home/RAD/01align/out/R40.bam > /home/RAD/01align/out/R40.PE.bam && echo '3 done'", "params": [], "version": null, "incomplete": false, "input": ["/home/RAD/01align/out/R40.bam"], "code": "gAMoQxR0AABkAQBkAgB8CgCDAQEBZAAAU3EAKFgFAAAAaW5wdXRxAVgGAAAAb3V0cHV0cQJYBgAAAHBhcmFtc3EDWAkAAAB3aWxkY2FyZHNxBFgHAAAAdGhyZWFkc3EFWAkAAAByZXNvdXJjZXNxBlgDAAAAbG9ncQdYBwAAAHZlcnNpb25xCFgEAAAAcnVsZXEJWAkAAABjb25kYV9lbnZxClgMAAAAYmVuY2hfcmVjb3JkcQt0cQxdcQ0oTlhYAAAAL25mcy9iaW9zb2Z0L3NhbXRvb2xzL3NhbXRvb2xzIHZpZXcgLWJGIDEyIHtpbnB1dC5iYW19ID4ge291dHB1dC5QRWJhbX0gJiYgZWNobyAnMyBkb25lJ3EOaAtlWAUAAABzaGVsbHEPhXEQdHERLg==", "log": []}
```

The code section may contain some help information for me to get the sample name. But I don’t know how to generate these code value.

I hope someone could help me out.

Answer (score 1):

The portable solution to this is to specify a log file for the rule. See [the docs](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#log-files). Also have a look at the best practice workflow(s) from the [Snakemake workflows project](http://github.com/snakemake-workflows/docs).

Comment: These jobs cost almost one week. Change the snakemake file and redo these jobs is my last choice. I hope I can find some information from the encrypted code from metadata.